# It is "not supported" to build or publish a self-contained application without specifying a RuntimeIdentifier

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, .net-core

Using the latest Visual Studio 2019 I am trying to publish a Msix installer for a DotNetCore 3.1 WPF application. The application builds and runs correctly, but when I try to publish the application I get this error

`It is not supported to build or publish a self-contained application without specifying a RuntimeIdentifier.`

My UI projects csproj looks like this.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win10-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
</PropertyGroup>
```

How can this issue be fixed?

Edit: So it turns out that the issue only occurs when I include my self hosted asp.net core project in the gui project that I am trying to package.

What could be causing this issue? Is it just not supported to package that kind of project for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

Please delete the RuntimeIdentifier and SelfContained setting in your PropertyGroup, then input **dotnet publish -f netcoreapp3.1 -r win10-x64 --self-contained false** in the cmd.exe

Comment: I tried this and this is the result I had.

https://pastebin.com/TehQtSix

And here is the end of the verbose version

https://pastebin.com/YCRetmHi

Comment: So it turns out that the issue only occurs when I include my self hosted asp.net core project in the gui project that I am trying to package.

What could be causing this issue? Is it just not supported to package that kind of project for some reason?

Comment: How did you include the asp.net core project in the gui project ? I need the details to reproduce the error.

Comment: The asp.net core project is referenced as a project reference by the wpf gui project. The wpf gui project self hosts the asp.net project. If I remove this reference (and the few lines of code that call into it) then it packages correctly.

Comment: Did you need any more info? I cannot think of anything else to add.

Comment: You can't make a self-contained ASP.NET project yet. They are still working on it.